# Uber price/time estimate API now returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, uber-api

I have been using an ionic app that I integrated Uber API time and price estimates for. I have registered my app in the uber developer studio and am including the server_token in the
requests like shown below. These were working fine from my app about a month or two ago but now I am getting 401 unauthorized "No authentication provided." error. When I take the same
URL with the server token and copy and paste into a new browser window I am able to get the response back with estimates. Am I missing something? These were working for me earlier and I am not logging the users
into Uber just want to get general price/time estimates. I have not setup any general scopes for the app since I thought those are only needed for OAuth. Do I need to request these for the estimate API calls too?

```
https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=%2033.8075191&start_longitude=-84.3750251&end_latitude=33.8092502&end_longitude=%20-84.36099030000003&server_token=<SERVER_TOKEN>
```

Here is the code block i am using to call the API URL

```
    var uberPricePromise = $http.get(createUberUrlForMetric('price'))
      .then(function (response) {

        var uberPrices = response;

        // format price from Uber for the view

      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });


    function createUberUrlForMetric(metric) {
      return 'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/' + metric + '?start_latitude= ' + PlacesService.currentLocation.lat +
      '&start_longitude=' + PlacesService.currentLocation.lng +
      '&end_latitude=' + $scope.place.geometry.location.lat() +
      '&end_longitude= ' + $scope.place.geometry.location.lng() +
      '&server_token=<SERVER_TOKEN>;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code otherwise anyone wanting to help can only guess. Read [mcve]

Comment: @SurajRao Added Code block to show how the URL is being called, if you have an insight into why im getting the 401 calling it from the app please let me know, as i mentioned I can copy the same url to another browser window and the API returns a response successfully

Answer (score 0):

Uber API version 1.0 is deprecated for the estimate endpoint, you can use the v1.2 instead and here is an example snippet for getting the estimate
More info can be found [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get)

Estimate endpoint can be used with a server_token or a bearer token

To use a `server_token`:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token <SERVER_TOKEN>' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075'
```

To use a user `access token`:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075'
```

So the change you might need to make to get your code working is passing the Server Token in Request Header instead of HTTP GET param.